# How to set ha-all policy when declare queue in python aio_pika?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, aio

I want to know how to declare queue with policy in python aiopika. I have trouble when I set **ha-all** policy in declare queue with python aio_pika. But, I couldn't declare policy in queue. I can only declare in feature arguments.

This picture is what I want.

[image]

But I have no idea for declaring policy.In this picture, ha-all policy is in arguments.

[image]